# Query dsl - Looping through a list to create OR predicates

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, querydsl

How do I dynamically create "OR" predicates if I have a `List<List<String>>`
I am using query dsl and spring data.

```
QOrder order = QOrder.order;
JPQLQuery<Order> query = from(order);
query.where(order.status.eq("ready"));
List<List<String>> filterTypes;
```

This is what I am trying to do:

```
for(List<String> types : filterTypes) {
    query.where(order.type.in(types));
}
```

So the result should be something like

```
select * from order o where o.status='ready' and (o.type in(t1,t2) or o.type in(t3,t4))
```

Answer (score 0):

To directly answer your question: assuming you're using a relatively modern version of QueryDSL, you should be able to use a `BooleanBuilder`:

```java
QOrder order = QOrder.order;
SQLQuery<Order> query = from(order);
query.where(order.status.eq("ready"));
// Example data
List<List<String>> filterTypes = ImmutableList.of(
        ImmutableList.of("t1", "t2"),
        ImmutableList.of("t3", "t4"));

BooleanBuilder builder = new BooleanBuilder();

for (List<String> types : filterTypes) {
    builder.or(order.type.in(types));
}

query.where(builder);
```

Backing up, assuming your actual application data model is similar to the example you provided, this:

```sql
o.type in (t1,t2) or o.type in (t3,t4)
```

Is equivalent to:

```sql
o.type in (t1,t2,t3,t4)
```

You could translate your `List<List<String>>` into `List<String>` and do your type query update once:

```java
QOrder order = QOrder.order;
SQLQuery<Order> query = from(order);
query.where(order.status.eq("ready"));
// Example data
List<List<String>> filterTypes = ImmutableList.of(
        ImmutableList.of("t1", "t2"),
        ImmutableList.of("t3", "t4"));
List<String> flatFilterTypes = filterTypes.stream().flatMap(List::stream).collect(Collectors.toList());
query.where(order.type.in(flatFilterTypes));
```

I *suspect* that your database's query optimizer would do the same thing for either query (you'd have to check a [query execution plan to be sure](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/using-explain.html)), but it'd probably be more clear what's going on if you did simplified the query on the Java side rather than relying on the database query optimizer.